# Ajax is caching the previous output of a form onlick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, caching

I have a form where i have multiple divisions which represents different activity.Now i have implemented a functionality which will get a list of data from the database.Each click on each division will populate data from the database via ajax call.I have implemented the functionality properly,i am getting the data from the database on each click on the division via ajax call.But my problem is that each time when the form is loaded,i click on a division the division gets the data via ajax call and show that data is a modal window,but now when i click on another division the same set of data is populating.The problem is that any division that is clicked first will populate the corresponding  dataset of that division and when we click on another division the previous data is showing..This is my code..

```
   <script>

function getUnUsedSTPCode(id){

var WindowHeader = "STP CODE LIST";
var htmlContent = $("#dashBoardDetails");
var myTable = "<table>";


$.ajax( 
                { 
                url: "getDashBoardData.do?method=getUnUsedSTPCode", 
                type: 'POST', 
                cache: false, 
                dataType: 'json', 
                data:{"storeId":id},
                    beforeSend: function() 
                    { 

                }, 
                success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) 
                { 

                      $.each(data, function(i, obj) {

                            myTable += "<tr><td>"+obj+"<//td><//tr>";                                
                        });


                      myTable += "<//table>" ;    
                      htmlContent.append(myTable); 
                      openWindow(WindowHeader);

                }, 
                error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) 
                { 
                       alert('error');   
                } 
               } 
        ); 

}
</script>

<script>

function getUserStatusInfo(status){

var WindowHeader = "REGISTERED USERS IN DRAFT MODE";
var htmlContent = $("#dashBoardDetails");
var myTable = "<table>";

$.ajax({

    url:"getDashBoardData.do?method=getRegisteredUserDetail",
    type:'POST',
    cache:false,
    dataType:'json',
    data:{"status":status},
    beforeSend:function(){

    },
    success:function(data,textStatus,xhr){
    var i=0;    
         $.each(data, function(i, obj) {
             var row="";
             if(i%2==0)
             row= "<tr class='even'>";
             else
             row= "<tr class='odd'>";    

            row += "<td>"+obj.firstName+"<//td>"+"<td>"+obj.lastName+"<//td>"+"<td>"+ obj.loginName +"<//td>"+ obj.orgContactid +"<//td>"+ obj.loginName +"<//td>"; 
            row +="<//tr>";
             myTable +=row;
         i++;
        });


      myTable += "<//table>" ;    
      htmlContent.append(myTable); 
      openWindow(WindowHeader);

    },

    error:function(xhr,textStatus,errorThrown){
        alert('error');
    }



});



}

</script>


 <form action="/getDashBoardData" name="tmlDashBoardForm" method="post" id="DashBoardData" >
<div id="wrapper"> 
  <div id="content">  
      <div class="demo">
        <h2 align="center">DASHBOARD</h2>

  <h3 class="expand collapse-close" onclick="getUnUsedSTPCode('100')">STPCODE NOT REGISTERED &nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="images/rr.png"/> <bean:write name="adminDashBoard" property="unUsedSTPCodeCount"  /> <span></span>  </h3>      
        <div class="collapse">

        </div>                    

        <h3 class="expand collapse-close" onclick="getUserStatusInfo('D')">REGISTERED USERS IN DRAFT MODE <img src="images/rr.png"/><bean:write name="adminDashBoard" property="draftUserCount" /> <span></span> </h3>
        <div class="collapse">
            <p>List of  user in draft mode are here</p>
        </div>                    
        <h3 class="expand collapse-close">PAYMENT INITIATED FOR USERS <img src="images/rr.png"/><bean:write name="adminDashBoard" property="paymentInitiatedCount" /><span></span> </h3>
        <div class="collapse">
            <p>Total number of users who have their payment initiated</p>
        </div>                   
        <h3 class="expand collapse-close"> PAYMENT RECIEVED FOR USERS <img src="images/rr.png"/><bean:write name="adminDashBoard" property="paymentReceivedCount" /> <span></span> </h3>
        <div class="collapse">
            <p>Total number of users who have their payment received</p>
        </div>                       
        <h3 class="expand collapse-close">PAYMENT DISAPPROVED FOR USERS <img src="images/rr.png"/><bean:write name="adminDashBoard" property="paymentDisApprovedCount" /><span></span> </h3>
        <div class="collapse">
            <p>Total number of users who have their payment disapproved</p>
        </div>  
         <h3 class="expand collapse-close">NUMBER OF ACTIVE USERS <img src="images/rr.png"/><bean:write name="adminDashBoard" property="activeUserCount" /><span></span> </h3>
        <div class="collapse">
            <p>Total number of users who are active</p>
        </div>   
         <h3 class="expand collapse-close">PAYMENT REALIZED WAITING FOR APPROVAL <img src="images/rr.png"/><bean:write name="adminDashBoard" property="paymentApprovalWaitingCount" /><span></span> </h3>
        <div class="collapse">
            <p>PAYMENT REALIZED WAITING FOR APPROVAL</p>
        </div>  
        <h3 class="expand collapse-close">PAYMENT RECEIVED WAITING FOR CLEARANCE <img src="images/rr.png"/><bean:write name="adminDashBoard" property="paymentWaitingForClearence" /><span></span> </h3>
        <div class="collapse">
            <p>PAYMENT RECEIVED, WAITING FOR CLEARANCE</p>
        </div>             
          <h3 class="expand collapse-close">PAYMENT REJECT <img src="images/rr.png"/><bean:write name="adminDashBoard" property="payementRejectedCount" /><span></span> </h3>
        <div class="collapse">
            <p> PAYMENT REJECT</p>
        </div>   
         <h3 class="expand collapse-close"> PAYMENT FAILED <img src="images/rr.png"/><bean:write name="adminDashBoard" property="payementFailedCount" /><span></span> </h3>
        <div class="collapse">
            <p> PAYMENT FAILED</p>
        </div> 
      </div>          
    </div>
</div>

<div id="modalalertdiv" style="display:block;">

<div style="background: #F3F3F3; height: 100%; padding: 5px ; overflow: scroll" id="dashBoardDetails"  >

</div>

</div>
</form>
```

when i click on STPCODE NOT REGISTERED division then the list is populating,when i click on REGISTERED USERS IN DRAFT MODE  division then the list is populating.But if i click STPCODE NOT REGISTERED first then after closing the window if i click REGISTERED USERS IN DRAFT MODE division the previous  list is showing.And the vice versa.
Somebody please help.

Noting is changing even if i do this

```
function getUnUsedSTPCode(id){

var WindowHeader = "STP CODE LIST";
var htmlContent = $("#dashBoardDetails");



$.ajax( 
                { 
                url: "getDashBoardData.do?method=getUnUsedSTPCode", 
                type: 'POST', 
                cache: false, 
                dataType: 'json', 
                data:{"storeId":id},
                    beforeSend: function() 
                    { 

                }, 
                success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) 
                { 
                      var myTable = "<table>";
                      $.each(data, function(i, obj) {

                            myTable += "<tr><td>"+obj+"<//td><//tr>";                                
                        });


                      myTable += "<//table>" ;    
                      htmlContent.html(myTable); 
                      openWindow(WindowHeader);

                }, 
                error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) 
                { 
                       alert('error');   
                } 
            } 
    );
```

}

Comment: Have anyone any idea about this???

Answer (score 0):

You are using `myTable` as a global variable and constantly appending to it. So `myTable` will always have the value of the first call (appended with the value of the second call, etc).

Furthermore, you're using `htmlContent.append(myTable);`, which will continually append the data to the div without ever removing what you first appended.

Try either declaring `myTable` inside the success function or resetting it inside the success function and using `.html` instead of `.append`:

```
success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) 
{ 
    var myTable = "<table>";
    $.each(data, function(i, obj) {
        myTable += "<tr><td>"+obj+"<//td><//tr>";                                
    });


    myTable += "<//table>" ;    
    htmlContent.html(myTable); 
    openWindow(WindowHeader);
},
```

Comment: i can not understand why it is caching the data please help

Comment: can i check current timestap before calling the actions??

Answer (score 0):

Even though you have given `cache:false,`

> **cache** (default: true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp')
>   If set to false, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the browser. 
>   Note: Setting cache to false will only work correctly with HEAD and GET requests. 
>   It works by appending "_={timestamp}" to the GET parameters. The parameter is not needed for other types of requests, except in IE8 when a POST is made to a URL that has already been requested by a GET.

[JQuery API - AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)